# Why allow List conversion to Map without merge function?

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, hashmap, collectors

Being relatively new to Java 8 I would like to know why it allows first variant(`merge` function not necessary) of `Collectors.toMap()` when working with `List`:

```
static <T,K,U> Collector<T,?,Map<K,U>>  toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K> keyMapper, Function<? super T,? extends U> valueMapper)
```

A `List` allows ENTIRELY DUPLICATE values. Imagine a use case where a developer uses `stream` to convert `List` to `Map` and java 8 exposes the RUNTIME as:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key ...
```

Shouldn't this scenario be required to be catched at compile time? AFAIK, hashmap used to simply replace old `Entry` when a duplicate `key` is put. If a developer is sure of the duplicate values in data and wants to handle this exception as a warning, won't he first use `Set` instead of `List`?
Eg. :-

```
public class Employee{
    public String name;
    public String surname;
    public Employee(String firstname, String secondName) {
        this.name=firstname;this.surname=secondName;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        return (o instanceof Employee) && ((Employee)o).name.equals(this.name) && ((Employee)o).surname.equals(this.surname);
    }
    public int hashCode(){
        return (name+surname).toCharArray().length;
    }
    public String primaryKey(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Set<Employee> set = new HashSet<>();
        ArrayList<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Employee one = new Employee("firstname","secondName");
        Employee two = new Employee("firstname","secondName");
        list.add(one);list.add(two); //allows entirely duplicate
        Map<String,Employee> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        for(Employee employee:list){
            //replace old employees in the order maintained by list before java 8
            hashMap.put(employee.primaryKey(), employee);
            //or may be use list inside some hashmap
        }
        set.add(one);set.add(two); //we can handle duplicates just by using sets
        Map<String,Employee> dontNeedListAsValues=set.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::primaryKey,o->o));
        Map<String, Employee> needListAsValues=list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::primaryKey, o -> o)); //currently ALLOWED for LIST
    }
}
```

Comment: Yippee just filled my stackoverflow survey lovely guys

Comment: Still waiting for correction in java?

Comment: What do you mean, waiting for correction?

Comment: awesome question when i look back at this today,cheers again!

Answer (score 8):

There are several reasons this is not a thing:

- There is only one `Stream` type, which is the same between `List` and `Set`.
- There is only one `Collector` type, so different `Collector`s can't work for only specific kinds of streams.
- Finally, the overhead of converting to a `Set` is significant and often not worth it for this specific case, when you know the keys will be unique.

Answer (score 0):

`Collectors.toMap` already has a merge function that can be used for that.

```
  Map<String, Employee> // need proper value for accepting merge
     needListAsValues=list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::primaryKey, o -> o,
         (a,b) -> <merge BinaryOperator here>));
```

Or

```
 Map<String, List<Employee>> 
     needListAsValues=list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::primaryKey));
```

But there are many situations in coding where it's up to the programmer to ensure that `RunTime` exceptions don't happen or are dealt with appropriately.

Comment: I did.  Why add additional functionality to a List that sources a stream when it isn't necessary as there are already ways to do a merge.  If you start writing extra methods or classes to cater to every possibility the API would get bloated and harder to maintain.  This is related to why many of the methods that  support `double`, `int`, and `long` and their array equivalents don't have `char`, `byte`, `float`, and, `short` equivalents.

Comment: Ok. But my dimple point is that Java inventors  should think before giving me toMap that list allows duplicate

Comment: It is very difficult design an API that guarantees that programmers cannot occasionally shoot themselves in the foot.  And when you try too hard to do that, you end up with a crippled API and/or a fundamentally inefficient design.  (And this also explains why a programmer may deliberately use a `List` to represent a collection that should always have unique elements.)

Comment: What about a `toMap` that requires you to specify a merge function even if you don't need one.  Many times I have wanted to specify a different map implementation via the `Supplier`.  But that three argument method doesn't exist. So I must specify the one with the merge method even if it isn't used.  So I specify it and move on.  The burden is on me to be aware of the API and deal with it.  And then there's operator overloading.  It would make `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` so much easier to use.  But it complicates the compiler design and other aspects of Java.

Comment: Why can't we just remove the first variant and make the merge function mandatory for compilation? Isn't it enough to remember that my list allows duplicates? Why increase my lines by converting list to set to list?